# Get object id of newly created object of Neo4j using c#

Tags: c#, neo4j

Once I added Label, node, or properties using the c# function I want to return the newly created objectId or name. How it's possible?

Below I am giving my code below

```
 public class clsAddNeo4jLabel 
    {
 private IDriver _driver;
        public clsAddNeo4jLabel()
        {
            _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("Binu2", "Binu2"));
        }


public void AddNode()
{
    string  labelName=Person
    string nodeName=Binu
using (var session = _driver.Session())
                {

            //        // Adding node working
                    var add = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
                    {
                        var result = tx.Run("CREATE (a:"+ labelName+") " +
                                           "SET a.name = $nodeName " +
                                            "RETURN a.name + ', from node ' + id(a)",
                           new { nodeName });

                        return result.Single()[0].As<string>();
                    });

               }
}


}
```

Comment: How are you creating object?

Comment: add some code, what are you currently have